# Strapi GitHub Hook, not seeing latest changes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, github, strapi

I have a production AWS EC2 running my strapi instance. I followed these instructions to set it up: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html#amazon-aws

I created a webhook in github, just like the docs say here: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html#set-up-a-webhook

I can confirm that the webhook is working by going to my github settings and seeing a 200 status under the webhook tab being returned.

So my question is, when will I see my changes in my production instance? The documentation states:

> (This script creates a variable called PM2_CMD which is used after
> pulling from GitHub to update your project. The script first changes
> to the home directory and then runs the variable PM2_CMD as pm2
> restart strapi. The project uses the ecosystem.config.js as the point
> of starting your application.)

How do I make this happen?